# If $A\subset\mathbb{C}$ is closed and $b\in\mathbb{C}$, then there exists $\alpha\in A$ such that $|\alpha-b|=\inf\{|a-b|:a\in A\}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Show that if $A\subset\mathbb{C}$ is closed and $b\in\mathbb{C}$, then there exists some $\alpha\in A$ such that $|\alpha-b|=\inf\{|a-b|:a\in A\}$.

**Attempt:**

We know, since $|x|\geq0$ for all $x$, that the set $S=\{|a-b|:a\in A\}$ is bounded below by zero. Therefore, it has a greatest lower bound $\inf S$. If such a point $\alpha$ exists such that $\inf\{|a-b|:a\in A\}=|\alpha-b|$, then we must have that $|\alpha-b|=\inf S$. Such an element of $S$ exists if and only if $\inf S\in S$, i.e. the set $S$ contains its greatest lower bound.

I have been unable to proceed from here. If I could show that $S$ contains its least upper bound, then I would be done, since such an $\alpha$ would be guaranteed to exist. This must follow somehow from the fact that $A$ is closed. Do I need to show that the set $\{|a-b|:a\in A\}$ is also closed? In this case, the set must contain its infimum, and we are done. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: The line $|a-b| = \inf\{|a-b| : a\in A\}$ does not make sense.

Comment: Show that this $inf\text{S}$ is a limit point of $A$.

Comment: @amsmath I suppose I should distinguish more. I will edit.

Comment: @amsmath in the set in the inf, $a$ is a dummy variable.

Comment: Is $C$ supposed to be $\mathbb C$?  Is the definition of "closed" the definition for metric space?  Use that $A$ is closed.

Comment: @fleablood yes, $\mathbf{C}=\mathbb{C}$, and the definition of closed is that every convergent sequence of elements in $A$ converges in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\beta$ denote the infimum of your set, and let $n$ be a positive integer.
By definition of the infimum, $\beta+\frac{1}{n}$ is not a lower bound. Therefore there exists $a_n\in A$ such that $|a_n-b|<\beta+\frac{1}{n}$. Since we also have $|a_n-b|\geq\beta$, we must have: $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n-b|=\beta$. A simple argument proves that $a_n$ itself is a convergent sequence. Since $A$ is closed, its limit must be in $A$, say, $\alpha$, and so you have $|\alpha-b|=\beta$.